# Cross-compiled with an incompatible version

Tags: eclipse, scala, m2eclipse, m2e, scala-ide

I am using eclipse with `m2eclipse-scala` plugin. Currently, I get the following error message:

`exampleA_2.10-2.0.1.jar of module build path is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.10.0). In case this report is mistaken, this check can be disabled in the compiler preference page`

It looks like the versions of extracted Scala and Scala IDE match. I just wanted to make sure that this is a ["false-negative"](http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/faq/index.html) as described here and can be safely turned off.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I doubt it is a false positive, but it's impossible to say based on the information you've given us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @The Archetypal Paul suggested, it was because I was using wrong Scala library.

If you are using Scala 2.11 (check at `About Scala IDE -> installation details`), you can downgrade by following instruction [here](http://scala-ide.org/blog/Xsource-compatibility.html). It's a lot easier than uninstalling and re-installing Scala IDE as other Stackoverflow posts recommend.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue->
I am trying to use casbah jar in scala to integrate with mongodb.

After analyzing the problem i found that ->
i am trying to use casbah 2.9.1 version and my scala version is 2.11.8

Root-Cause of such error is : your jar is compiled in 2.9.0 version and you are using scala 2.11.8 version

So, to resolve that i use the jar that is compiled into 2.11 scala version-

```
<groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
<artifactId>casbah-core_2.11</artifactId>
<version>3.1.1</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue in Eclipse IDE where I had built a Spark scala project in Maven. The scala version was set to 2.11. 
Later, I upgraded Scala-Ide plugin in Eclipse after which my project marked below errors,

exampleA_2.10-2.0.1.jar of module build path is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.10.0). In case this report is mistaken, this check can be disabled in the compiler preference page

Right click project folder > scala > set scala version. Here my scala version was displayed as 2.10. I selected 2.11 and removed all the error messages.